# Laravel with Homestead

Tags: php, laravel-4, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I new with virtual box  and vagrant , Now I using Homestead image and every thing is run well 
but when i create my project named laravel on virtual machine it supposed that i see this new folder named laravel  on my machine but i didn't get any thing on my machine.

- when i type url http://homestead.app:8000/ i get This webpage is not available
- The synchronization is not working  and

NOTE: - I'm using ubuntu 14.04

This is my homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

keys:

```
 - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

folders:

```
  - map: /var/projects/
    to: /home/vagrant/projects/
```

sites:

```
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/projects/laravel/public
```

variables:

```
- key: APP_ENV
  value: local
```

thanks advance

Comment: You skipped a tab before to in your folders section. Yaml is very sensitive to indentation so that might be it

Comment: I review it in my .yaml file it is write in correct way but when i write the question i do by mistake this tab.

Answer (score 0):

> ...when i create my project named laravel on virtual machine it
>   supposed that i see this new folder named laravel on my machine...

I've run into this before. The root laravel project folder needs to be created on your *real* machine first. Then setup the site folder mapping above as you have done.

Then afterwards any further changes inside the virtual machine will replicate/sync both ways.

Comment: - I create folder named laravel on my machine and create a new project  again nothing happen.




- when i go to url  when i type url http://homestead.app:8000/  i get This webpage is not available

Comment: I do vagrant destroy then vagrant up , and it is the same result i has  before .

Comment: I had same error message. My laravel folder was created elsewhere.

Check to make sure the folder from map sites exists: /home/vagrant/projects/laravel/public

If not move the folder created when you created your Laravel project to the folder on your base machine.